# Turn SAS date into week day of year ending on last Friday

Tags: sas

I'm trying to manipulate my Dispensing_Date to give me the weeknum of the year ending on last Friday for each Date, can this be done? Here is what I have so far...

```
%let 1= 01012016;
%let 53 = 12302016;

**01 import whiteoak file;
proc import
    datafile = "E:\Horizon\Adhoc\AH\whiteoak.xlsx"
    out = whiteoak
    dbms = XLSX
    replace;
run;

** 02 remove dupes to ensure unique rx and fill;
proc sort nodup data=whiteoak;
by Rx_ Refill;
run;

** 03 Filter out holds;
data whiteoak;
set whiteoak;
where (Filled_Status="YES");
run;

** 04 create weekday variable;
data dates;
set whiteoak;
format Dispensing_Date MMDDYY8.;
run;
```

Comment: Can you provide and example using data?

Comment: that is my data...I need to turn Dispensing Date into a weeknumber and add it either to whiteoak dataset or a new dataset, can I use week(Dispensing_Date, 'w') ; somewhere?

Comment: Can I create a weekday variable from the Dispensing_date from my whiteoak table?

Comment: I'm asking you to show example of what you have and what you want.  If disp date is today what is the date you expect (the answer)?

Comment: Dispensing_Date is a column with many different dates in it...is there a way to just extract the weeknumber of the year from whatever date is in that column?

Comment: Isn't that what you do with WEEK=WEEK(dispensing_date);?

Comment: Please post some example dates and the desired WEEK value for those dates.  Pick a few where the WEEK() function does not return the result you want. Also are you sure your date variable is actually a date and not just a number like 11,252,015 that looks like a valid mmddyyyy value?

Comment: ok, so far, I can't even get a column_name to show up as week or week number, i'd like to create a dataset that includes whiteoak data and converts the dates in the dispensing_date column into week number of the year ending in Friday endings...so 12/30/2016 should be whatever week number it is in the week ending on that date...maybe I'm just not good enough in SAS to explain what I want...if I input 12/30/2016 in Excel then I get the weeknumber 53, however i'd need to ensure that converts it to a Friday ending week

Comment: Use a calendar and count the weeks yourself to create your example data.

Comment: sure, of course, just wanted to try and do it SAS.

Comment: Once you post some useful sample data then someone can help with the SAS code. Until then we are just taking guesses at what you really want.

Comment: You also have to define what is the first week of the year--the week containing the first Friday (which might include some of the past year) or the first full week of the year? There is some discussion in [this other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833053/sas-get-week-number-for-each-month).

Comment: ok YES! The week containing the first Friday so that would January 1st, 2016...how do I define that and then how do I create a new column to change my Dispensing date column from whiteoak dataset to convert to the number based on this variable?

Comment: In the future please follow the instructions here on providing an example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess as to what you are asking.

```
24         data _null_;
25            x = today();
26            d = intnx('week.7',x,-1,'end');
27            put (_all_)(=weekdate.);
28            run;

x=Wednesday, January 4, 2017 d=Friday, December 30, 2016
```

Comment: Now how do I incorporate this into my whiteoak table so that a new column is created called 'weeknum' and so it extracts the weeknumber of the year from whatever is in the dispensing_date column?

Comment: Use the function in the line D= and move it to your data step or include it in a new dataset. X is the date, so change that to refer to the date. Look at the documentation for INTNX to make sure it's what you want and what the parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
data weeks;
  do date = '22DEC2016'd to '15JAN2017'd;
    format date first_friday weekdate.;
    sas_week=week(date);
    first_friday= intnx('week.7',intnx('year',date,0,'b'),0,'e');
    friday_week=1+int((7+date-first_friday)/7) ;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

If it does then apply it to your data:

```
data dates;
  set whiteoak;
  week = 1 + int((7+Dispensing_Date
       - intnx('week.7',intnx('year',Dispensing_Date,0,'b'),0,'e'))/7);
run;
```

Comment: yes!!! Now is there a way to incorporate this into my dataset called whiteoak so that I can pull other data for a certain week that lines up with my dates from dispensing_date?